# Magento2 get all the currencies for default store

Tags: magento2, currency

I have more than 5 currencies for my default store, I want to fetch all those currencies codes and symbols programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch the Allowed Currencies List using the below Code:

```
public function __construct(
    /* Add below dependencies */
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currencyModel
) {
    $this->currenciesModel = $currencyModel;
}

/*Call the below function to fetch Allow Currencies*/
 $this->currenciesModel->getConfigAllowCurrencies()
```

To get currencies code & symbol using standalone script:

```
use Magento\Store\Model\Store;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager;
use Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\CurrencyBundle as CurrencyBundle;

require 'app/bootstrap.php';

$params                                  = $_SERVER;
$params[StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE]    = 'admin';
$params[Store::CUSTOM_ENTRY_POINT_PARAM] = true;

$bootstrap     = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
$bootstrap->getObjectManager()->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode("frontend");
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();


$storeObj = $objectManager->create('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager')->getStore();
$codes = $storeObj->getAvailableCurrencyCodes(true);
$currencies = [];



if (is_array($codes) && count($codes) >= 1) {
    foreach ($codes as $code) {
            $allCurrencies = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Locale\Bundle\CurrencyBundle')->get(
                $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface')->getLocale()
            )['Currencies'];
            $currencies[$code]['title'] = $allCurrencies[$code][1] ?: $code;
            $currencies[$code]['symbol'] = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface')->getCurrency($code)->getSymbol();

    }
}
```

Comment: how can i try it in root folder

Comment: How to get the currency names

Comment: check the updated answer, you will get currency code, symbol and title

Comment: Hi, Pankaj, how can i get website code

Comment: you can get like this `$storeObj->getWebsite()->getCode();`

Answer (score 3):

Get currency codes, names, and symbol.

```
protected $storeManager;
protected $currencyInterface;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    \Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface $currencyInterface
) {
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->currencyInterface = $currencyInterface;
  }
  ...
  ...  

$availableCurrencies = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes();
$currencyNames = array();
$currencySymbol = array();

foreach ($availableCurrencies as $currencyCode) {
    $currencyNames[] = $this->currencyInterface->getCurrency($currencyCode)->getName();
    $currencySymbol[] = $this->currencyInterface->getCurrency($currencyCode)->getSymbol();
}

print_r($availableCurrencies);
print_r($currencyNames);
print_r($currencySymbol);
```

If you want to test it on root folder, use below method.

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ .'/app/bootstrap.php';
$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
// Set the state (not sure if this is neccessary)
$state = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

// Our code for getting currencies starts from here

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$currencyInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\CurrencyInterface');

$availableCurrencies = $storeManager->getStore()->getAvailableCurrencyCodes();
$currencyNames = array();
$currencySymbol = array();

foreach ($availableCurrencies as $currencyCode) {
    $currencyNames[] = $currencyInterface->getCurrency($currencyCode)->getName();
    $currencySymbol[] = $currencyInterface->getCurrency($currencyCode)->getSymbol();
}

print_r($availableCurrencies);
print_r($currencyNames);
print_r($currencySymbol);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code :

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
    \Magento\Directory\Model\Currency $currency,        
    array $data = []
)
{        
    $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    $this->_currency = $currency;        
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
}
/**
 * Get array of installed currencies for the scope
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getAllowedCurrencies()
{
    return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getAllowedCurrencies();
}
/**
 * Get currency symbol for current locale and currency code
 *
 * @return string
 */    
public function getCurrentCurrencySymbol()
{
    return $this->_currency->getCurrencySymbol();
}
```